# Correct API approach for long processing time

Tags: http

I am making an HTTP web API that's mainly fed by a database. Simplified, the db contains userobjects.
These objects have a `last_online` (when the user was online) and `last_checked` (the last time I *checked the userobject*).

*Checking the userobject* can take from 3 to 30 seconds. When the `last_checked` time is less than 10 minutes then everything's okay; API call returns `200` and the userobject.

But I want to reprocess the userobject when the data is staler than 10 minutes. Obviously I can not have my API return sit there and wait.

**What is the right approach to HTTP APIs that (sometimes) need to return data from long running processes?**

Comment: What sort of API are you talking about? A web API? A library in some specific language? If so, which language?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794696/best-http-status-code-in-rest-api-for-not-ready-yet-try-again-later

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first proposal would be to have the server update the user object every X minutes as a background process. I don't see any reason to place the burden of keeping server data up-to-date on the client. Responses to the `GET` call would include an [Expires](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.21) header. The client could then cache the response for a fixed amount of time, saving you server hits until the data gets refreshed.

If you must make the refresh be client-driven, you want your `GET` to return a `202 Accepted`, which indicates a valid request that the API is working on but has not completed. The entity that gets returned from your `GET` request should provide a timestamp for when the API should check back to get the updated data. Once the data has been refreshed, the `GET` will return a `200 Ok` with the refreshed data. This is the approach I recommend.

```
GET /userObject
<- 202 Accepted
{ "checkAt": <timestamp> }

GET /userObject
<- 200 OK
{ "userName": "Bob", ... }
```

You could also consider using the `Retry-After` header in your response, but that's only appropriate for `503 Service Unavailable` or any of the various `3xx (Redirection)` responses. You definitely aren't describing a `503`, and it doesn't sound like redirection is correct either.

If you do want to go the redirection route, you'd return a `302 Found`, specifying the temporary URI in the `Location` header and the delay time in the `Retry-After` header.

A fourth approach would be to use a `POST` and the [Post-Redirect-Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern. You could `POST` to your userObject URI and have it return the `302 Found` with the `Retry-After` header.

I really don't think that options three or four buy you anything that the second option doesn't, and I think it's the most clear. Three implies that your resource currently lives in a different location when it doesn't. Four transforms what is fundamentally a `GET` request (give me the user object) into a `POST` (refresh the user object, but only if you need to).

If you do decide to follow @JonSkeet's suggestion, you probably want a separate resource, something like `/userObjects` and `/userObjectRequests`. The client would always `POST` to `/userObjectRequests`. If the userObject was valid on the back end, that `POST` would return a `302` to `/userObjects`. If it wasn't valid, the `POST` would return an entity with an id and an estimated completion time. The client could call `GET` on `/userObjectRequests/{id}`, and they'd either get a `302` to the userObject (if it's ready) or a `200` with the id and a new estimated completion time.

Answer (score 4):

One fairly "old-school" way of handling this would be to return a continuation token - basically a job ID saying, "Check this periodically; sooner or later it'll come back with a result." Given that even 30 seconds is quite a long time, you might want to give back a continuation token even in the normal "checking" situation.

More modern alternatives would be web sockets or a hanging get... it really depends on what your client use cases are.

Comment: What would be the HTTP code for returning a token and acknowledging the request?

Comment: @GerbenJacobs: Well I'd assume you'd be returning the data as JSON - I'd just use 200, as it *is* a successful response in itself. It's possible that there's a more dedicated response code, but I'm not aware of it.

Comment: I'd return the job-id token in a `202` code ("Accepted")